# Word closest to the meaning of this sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

Upon reading this sentence in an article, I have tried to find the *best* word to synonymously insert for the sake of practice. (I felt that this question would be better answered in this forum)

The sentence is:

> "Rather than the familiar A through F in each subject, standards-based report cards might *feature* numbers or phrases that represent whether students have reached, exceeded, or yet met various specific performance expectations."

I would like to replace the word "*feature*" with either "*present*" or "*report*" because I feel like that is as best as it can get. Which word should I use to better capture the essence of the sentence and still have consistent meaning?

Comment: I'd expect 'use', plain and simple.

Comment: "comprise" in the sense of including items.

Answer (score 0):

*present* is a problem because *represent* comes five words later.

If I had to choose, I'd go with *report*.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think either is fine.

There is a case to be made for both I would say.

> report

This is truer to what the 'report' card is actually doing. After all that is the whole point of the card, to report. So I feel you have a more accurate representation of what you are actually doing with these "numbers or phrases" if you choose the word report.

The reason I am not sold on this, is that you have used the word report just three words prior to name your cards. There is no rule which says you can not duplicate words in close proximity like this but It does make the reader work fractionally harder as they have to parse the meaning again, in light of the report card itself which you have just mentioned.

The alternative you have suggested,

> present

Avoids this problem, but is not quite as perfect a fit in meaning, as you are doing more than just presenting this information, you are presenting it with an official purpose, as connotated in the context of the passage, with the word report.

So I would say either is fine.

For the purposes of the section you have quoted I do actually prefer the word 'feature' because this makes the aspect that is being featured take on a more central purpose to the document.

**feature**

> To include someone or something as an important part
>   
> [ref: Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feature)

Which is a key part of the passage I would say, as it places the emphasis on this key part of the revised document (the revised reporting), highlighting how important the aspect is, and how central it would be on the new document.

Comment: Even though report and present aren't the best, which would be a closer approximation of feature despite grammar, connotation, and style?

Comment: If we are looking strictly at meaning, and the choice is just these two words, relative to feature, (in the context of this passage) I would say report, because a report is "about a child's ability and performance at school" and 'present' is a very neutral word. There is the overtone of gravitas and importance to the word report when used in the way you are using it here, which present doesn't carry. I would say for that reason 'report' is a closer match to feature, purely for the fact it places some weight on the importance of the thing that is being reported. Whereas 'present', is neutral.